# How will you categorise the various software testing methods?

Tags: testing, testing-strategies

Would this be right??

1. Black Box

   1.1 Functional

   ```
       1.1.1 Equivalence
       1.1.2 BVA
       1.1.3 Use case
       1.1.4 Regression
       1.1.5 UAT
   ```

   1.2 Non Functional

   ```
       1.2.1 Testing the System Design
   ```
2. White box

   2.1. Functional

   ```
          2.1.1 Unit
          2.1.2 Integration
          2.1.3 System
   ```

**Do the above fall under the right categories?**

The reason I ask this is because as a part of a report I was trying to come up with a good reference that categorised Test Techniques well. This is what my analysis and research from various sources gave me. And I hope this is helpful for someone else who might be doing the same research, but if its incorrect it should be updated.

Answer (score 1):

You might also consider the case when several programs depending one on another are developed simultaneously. You have then to take into account the ***applicative architecture*** which groups all those applications into several *functional domains*

So, for instance, a financial application having to process a large number of data would be *one* functional domain, in which you would have to develop a:

- dispatcher module in order to process those data on several computers
- GUI in order to see what is going on
- launcher in order to initiate the right connections retrieve the correct data and format them
- and so on

But that would only be *one* functional domain, as others would have to be developed in order to *exploit the results* of your programs (for instance, a "referential domain" would be there to store those results into various databases, and offer a communication bus for other programs to access them: that would be a second functional domain).

So I would add to your tests the following categories:

- **Assembly testing**: when you test within your own functional domain (on an assembly server when you deploy the different applications of your domain, with a set of testing data)
- **Integration testing**: when you test ***all the applications from all the functional domains***, which is also called ***front-to-end testing***.

Note: "integration testing" is not the same as "continuous integration testing", which basically can process the black and white tests you describe, for ***one*** program, on a very regular basis.

The tests I am referring to are executed a few times a week by an:

- "*Project Operational Architecture*" team of your domain for assembly tests: usually some developers of your team which set up an assembly server, check if the data are up-to-date and deploy the various program you are in charge to develop.
- "*Production Operational Architectural*" team, in charge of setting a "production-like" environment and who is the only one able to really *test* the all chain of application from font to back.

Note: an "Operation Architecture" team has the role to "make operational an execution environment", meaning to have:

- the right logistic team contacts in order to have the right servers and networks,
- the right application teams contacts in order to know about the various start/stop application processes and deployment procedures of *all* the application of your system!

In short: your categories are for *one program*, but when you are developing an IS (Information System), you are forced to acknowledge the fact that you are not talking about "*one* exe developed by *one* team deployed on *one* production machine"... and then, welcome to an all new world of testing ;)

Answer (score 0):

I think that your categorisation is a good first step.

Separation between black box and white box (some prefer glass box) testing focuses on whether you have access only to the specification or more (design, source code).

I would add a second separation between functional and structural testing, which focuses on whether you want to consider what the software does (functional) or how it does it (structural).

A third separation deals with how you generate test inputs, deterministically or statistically (with a deliberate distribution and not randomly). Either way, your focus is on what coverage you target.

Finally a well known separation is between different levels of software cycle: unit testing, integration, system, acceptance, ...

Answer (score 0):

Following are the Testing methodologies broadly defined in the Software Testing:

**1. Black Box Testing** is a software testing method in which the internal structure/design/implementation of the item being tested is not known to the tester. These tests can be functional or non-functional, though usually functional. Test design techniques include: Equivalence partitioning, Boundary Value Analysis, Cause Effect Graphing.

**2. White Box Testing** is a software testing method in which the internal structure/design/implementation of the item being tested is known to the tester. Test design techniques include: Control flow testing, Data flow testing, Branch testing, and Path testing.

**3. Gray Box Testing** is a software testing method which is a combination of Black Box Testing method and White Box Testing method.